# Structural phase transition under uniaxial strain

Tags: quantum-espresso, geometry-optimization, stress-strain

I am trying calculate a strain-induced phase transition in some weakly correlated crystalline material using Quantum ESPRESSO (QE). The compound has two (experimentally observed) phases, one of which is a high temperature cubic phase and the other being hexagonal (present down to cryogenic temperatures). Calculating the energies under *isotropic* compression and fitting a common tangent to the curves, I find a moderate transition pressure of $700\,\mathrm{MPa}$. I would now like to calculate whether a similar transition occurs under uniaxial strain $\epsilon$, but I'm unsure about the correct methodology for this.
Currently I converge the cutoff energy, the $k$-point grid and the smearing energy, relax both structures in the variable cell approach and then apply uniaxial strain using $\epsilon = \frac{a-a_0}{a_0}$ where $a_0$ is the relaxed lattice parameter and $a$ is the lattice parameter under strain. Now I am unsure about how to continue:

1. Perform an scf-calculation with the strained structure?
2. Do a relaxation calculation, but keep the lattice parameters constant, moving just the atoms? (`relax` in QE)
3. Perform a variable cell relaxation, keeping the strained lattice parameter $a$ constant? (`vc-relax` with `cell_dofree = 'fixa'`)
4. Something else

Afterwards I would plot the energy per atom in the unit cell and see if at some point the energy of the ambient pressure phase becomes higher than the energy of the high temperature phase (similarly to Fig. 4 of [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/s12274-014-0626-5) reference). Is this a correct approach?

Comment: 2 and 3 both option can be used for such study just need to measure pressure at the end. It is important to note that, volumetric compresion/tension doesn't reduce symmetry of crystal but uniaxial tension compression does. Hence calculation will be computaional expansive.

Comment: @Pranavkumar Thank you for the clarification. I'm still a bit confused as 2) and 3) yield different final energies. Furthermore, pressure (as used in the tag `press` for example) is in my understanding an isotropic quantity that I can't use to describe uniaxial compression/expansion?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, did you figure this out now? I noticed you didn't visit the site for a couple of weeks it seems.

Comment: Thanks for you reply; I decided to go with 3), but my results were unfortunately experimentally not feasible. I am still not 100% sure though if that is the correct way to do it. [This](http://exciting.wikidot.com/fluorine-energy-vs-strain-calculations) link is the closest to a solution that I have found